What episode of Burn Notice was Michael drugged and kidnapped in?
This episode of Burn Notice had Michael trying to find a hacker to help him with a plan. The hacker is found and when Michael goes to meet the hacker, it is a girl. He gets in the car with her and feels a sharp pain in his hand. A syringe's needle pops out and he is kidnapped for a short period of time.

Have you used google? "Burn notice hacker" only turns up 2 episode possibilities.

It might have been a hacker.

It's Season 5 Episode 4, "No Good Deed". From WSJ:
Early in the episode:

Griffin brings Michael, who calls himself Baxter, to his employer, Eve, a vicious hacker who is playing dominoes for fun. Michael plays dumb, and gives her $10,000 upfront for a busy-work job. A quick-witted Fiona continues with her quips, noting from afar that Eve is “the real redhead I’ve seen since I left Ireland.”

Later on:

Meanwhile, Baxter gets picked up by the red-haired Eve, who laced a needle with Ketamine to drug him. She strangles him with a plastic bag after figuring out the account info he gave her was bogus.  He blames it on her boyfriend, who she exchanges frequent texts with. (Information Mike wouldn’t have without Max.)
In a bold move, Eve sits down with Fiona, Jesse and Sam, er, Chuck Finley. She’s got Baxter held up in a secret compound. He’s taking a “Ketamine nap.” She leaves an address and tells them to be there.


"The first real redhead", perhaps?
